Flatlist initialScrollIndex triggers onMomentumScroll
I have a Flatlist that I want to start at a fixed index rather than the first index so I set the initialScrollIndex prop. This works, however, has the side effect of triggering the onMomentumScroll event handler on component mount.
I understand I could create a hasMounted state variable to suppress events on mount but I'm wondering if there is a better way to handle this?
Snack
